# Partial Page Postback'ish MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

First, I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I'm new to MVC and am trying to get up to speed as quickly as possible. I have spent hours searching for answers and even went and bought a book on MVC 4, but it still didn't answer my question.

I have a form I'd like a user to fill out to add a new product to the catalog. They choose the category, enter the name, a description, etc.. On the same page I'd like them to be able to add sizes or product options such as Small, Medium, Large, etc.. The problem is I'm not sure how to go about this.

I need to temporarily store the size options for example in some sort of collection until the user actually 'saves' the product, then I need to be able to read the collection. What I'm trying to avoid is to have the user add the basic product info, then save it, then select it, then choose to add options to it. I'm trying to just do it all on one form.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand why you want to save the product before setting the options.  Why can't you just have the options be included in the initial save?  For example, having a dropdown list.  For example, user selects t-shirt, selects size, then clicks save.

Comment: I want to save the product AND the options at the same time. I don't know how to keep a running list of options the user adds before saving the product. Does that make sense?

Comment: You don't.  You just have input fields that contain the options, and when you save the form, all those options will be posted along with the rest of the data.  This is pretty basic HTML and has nothing whatsoever to do with MVC.

Comment: Ok, let me try this again. if you enter basic product info (name, desc, etc..) I also want the user to be able to add options. The options will need to be manually entered into a form (name, price, desc, etc..) they should be able to add multiple options to the product before saving it. If this was in ASP.NET WebForms then I would just do something like keep a generic List<> in ViewState of the options the user adds and then when they 'save' the product I would read the ViewState collection to get the list of options that should be saved along with the product.  Does that clarify?

Comment: You don't need the view state, because the options themselves stored in the UI are themselves the state.  If you add a textbox for price, then the textbox itself contains that data.  As such, there is no reason to save it to a view state.  I suspect you're looking for something like this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing preventing you creating a view model with its own collections for the detail items and have those mapped to some sort of javascript control for selecting multiple items such as one that writes to an mvc hidden form control.

The controller handling the postback will simply create the master model from the postback data (the updated view model) and then create the child records. The whole thing could be achieved with ajax calling a controller action that returns a partial view of the updated ui.

Similar to this but have the list as a property of the master model

http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201002/Blog/How-To-Handle-Multiple-Select-Lists-In-ASP-NET-MVC/

A little more advanced on how to manage your own bindings http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=584

Sounds like u need to roll your sleeves up and get a control written in javascript that allows child items to be added client side whist serializing e.g. Into json when they save and saving it to an mvc hidden control ready for postback. Use json.net to hydrate these values into your pocos. http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html